# Set the Style of a control programatically in Silverlight 4?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, styles

I am new to Silverlight, but I couldn't find anything about this when I googled it.

I have a button that I am trying to set the style programatically. I have the style defined in a XAML file and I want to pull the style into C# so I can dynamically create a button and assign it this style. So far, this is what I am trying:

```
button.Style = (Style)Resources["CloseButtonStyle"];
```

However, it just makes the button have no style. Is there an easy way to do this? I feel like this should be obvious, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that your `Resources` property on the current object is the one that contains the defined style. However, I assume, given the symptoms of your issue, that `CloseButtonStyle` is actually defined further up the control hierarchy.

Instead, you need to [traverse your control hierarchy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952%28VS.95%29.aspx#referencing_resources_from_code) until you find the resource (or if you know the object that defines it, just refer directly to that object). Unfortunately, Silverlight doesn't include `FindResource` call like WPF, but it's not too difficult to implement your own.

Comment: I figured it would be something like this. The style in question is defined in my "generic.xaml" file for the control I am writing. I assume this means I will have to go and find it manually, since FindResource doesn't exist? Is there any easy way to reference the "generic.xaml" file?

Comment: I don't believe you can programmatically access resources that are defined in generic.xaml (See [this forum post answer](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/32609/101446.aspx#101441) - seems to imply this isn't possible). Could you define the style in App.xaml instead?

Comment: Actually the implementation of FindResource is not trivial at all, have you seen its decompiled code?

Comment: I got around this by creating a button object in XAML and then referencing it to pull the style reference off of that. It seems a little ad hoc to do it my way, so I'm going to see if I can find a different solution to my problem here without need to reference the style programatically in the first place.

Comment: @H.B.: To do a full implementation that works exactly like the WPF version is pretty hard, but a simple version that looks up the resource in the current element's resources and then delegates to the parent control is not too difficult and suits most purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I can call `button1.Style = (Style)Resources["NonExistentKey"];` and it makes my button have no style at all as well, point being that the resource is probably not being found, you won't get an exception.

You directly access the `Resources` property, but is the style really in the immediate resource dictionary of your Window/UserControl/whatever-you-have?